# Replace server side @Url.Action with client side anchor tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc 5 app which shows a user's mails and when he clicks one of emails, another action shows the mail content. When i decided to enable paging for inbox, i implemented loading the mail list from an api by an ajax request.

How can i replace the server side @Url.Action with client side anchor tag address?

```
// This is server side code in the Inbox.chtml
<tr class="unread">
    <td class="mail-ontact"><a href="@Url.Action("EmailView", "Mailbox", new {Id=@Model.Id})">@Model.Name</a></td>     
    <td class="mail-subject"><a href="@Url.Action("EmailView", "Mailbox", new {Id=@Model.Id})">@Model.Subject</a></td> 
    <td class="text-right mail-date">@Model.Time</td>
</tr>


//  Client side implemetation
//
//  inside success function
<tr class="${isMailRead}>"
    <td class="mail-ontact"> <a href="????">${name}</a></td>     // ??? should be http://my-domain/Mailbox/EmailView/2
    <td class="mail-subject"><a href="????">${subject}</a></td>  // how can i replace my-domain with proper value ?
    <td class="text-right mail-date">${composeTime}</td>
</tr>
```

The problem is, i cannot hard code any domain name, since the product may be deployed on different domain names.

Comment: you could return partial view back from ajax call and append that html in a container div

Comment: it solves the problem for web application. but the consumer of the API is not just web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use URLs relative to the root of the site like `/MailBox/EmailView/${id}`.
Browser will include whatever domain the site is loaded on.